# Having trouble with function pointers and array

Tags: c

I am currently using Visual Studios for class and needless to say I am having difficulty understanding pointers. I have created a program but does not seem to work right for me. I keep getting an assertion error after I click the function type that I want. I get a Debug assertion failed pop up error. Expression: result_pointer != nullptr. It says line 1558

```
int function1(int a,int b);
int function2(int a, int b);
int function3(int a, int b);

int(*p[3])(int x, int y);

int main()
{

    int num1, num2;
    int choice = 0;

    p[0] = function1;
    p[1] = function2;
    p[2] = function3;

    printf("Please enter two numbers: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num1);
    scanf_s("%d", &num2);
    printf("Which would you like to try (1 for Math, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication): \n");
    scanf_s("%d", choice);
    int (*i) = &choice;

    while (*i >= 0 && *i < 3) {
        (p[*i])(num1,num2);
    }

puts("Program execution compiled");
}
int function1(int a, int b) 
{
    int total;
    total = a + b;
    return total;

}
int function2(int a, int b) 
{
    int total;
    total = a - b;
    return total;
}
int function3(int a, int b) 
{
    int total;
    total = a * b;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic? Have you tried stepping through in VS's debugger? What happens to the various variables?

Comment: Is the compiler giving you any warnings when you compile?

Comment: no when I build it goes through with no errors here is what comes up1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: pointer-function, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  pointer-function.cpp
1>c:\users\cesteves\documents\c programming\pointer-function\pointer-function\pointer-function.cpp(26): warning C4477: 'scanf_s' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'
1>  pointer-function.vcxproj -> C:\Users\cesteves\Documents\C Programming\pointer-function\Debug\pointer-function.exe
= Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped =

Comment: `scanf("%d", choice)` isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, that warning is telling you that on line 26, which is `scanf_s("%d",choice)`, you need to pass a pointer, but instead you passed an `int`. In other words line 26 should be `scanf_s("%d", &choice)`

Comment: The error message is not showing anymore but now I am having difficulty printf the outcome

Comment: The code doesn't try to `printf` the outcome. Also, the `while` loop will never end. The `while` should be `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why your code fails:

```
scanf_s("%d", choice);
```

You forgot to use the address of operator `&`.

```
scanf_s("%d", &choice);
```

Of course there are a number of other quirks with your code.

For example,

1. Why do you use `int (*i) = &choice;`? Wouldn't it make more sense just to take the `choice` and subtract `1`? No need to use pointers `int i = choice - 1`.
2. Your loop is going to execute the body of the loop until `i` is less than zero or greater than 2, which is never if the input entered is correct. Consider choosing another loop condition, or swapping the loop with an `if` statement.
3. You don't ever display the return value of the function. Try something like this `printf("%d\n", (p[i])(num1,num2)` (assuming you've fixed the `i` is a pointer thing)

Comment: I figured it out. The reason I used pointers is because the chapter was for the purpose of including pointers and I felt like I was not using them enough.

Comment: @Chris You used the address of operator `&` quite a few times, so you used a lot of pointers. You could probably skip the one I mentioned though.

Comment: thank you all for all of the great advice and suggestions!